# Payoff function of a 2-strategy game

Tags: game-theory

I have been studying the paper "Analysis and Control of Networked Game Dynamics via A Microscopic Deterministic Approach" by Tan, Wang and Lu.

[image]

In the second page it says that for a 2-strategy game the payoff function of each player from a networked game can be calculated by the last equation shown above.

How do we derive this equation?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payoff $f_i$ for Player $i$ is computed assuming that she plays each neighbor.  So the summation includes one term for each nonzero $a_{ik}$.  The payoff from Player $k$ to Player $i$ depends on both players' propensity to use Strategy $C$.  The probability that they both play $C$, for example, is $x_ix_k$.  If you take the matrix product, you get

$$ ax_ix_k + bx_i(1-x_k) + c(1-x_i)x_k + d(1-x_i)(1-x_j) \enspace, $$

which is the expected payoff for Player $i$.